# Deserialize XML with multiple namespaces to objects

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I´m trying to deserialize this XML to objects in C# .NET 4.5:

```
<DIDL-Lite xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
       xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"
       xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/">
    <item id="28" parentID="19" restricted="1">
        <dc:creator>Alicia Keys</dc:creator> 
        <dc:date>2003-01-01</dc:date>
        <dc:title>Gangsta Lovin&apos; (feat. Alicia Keys)</dc:title>
    </item>
</DIDL-Lite>
```

Code:

I´m not getting any "item" Lists. The object isn't deserialized.

```
MemoryStream reader = new MemmoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Result));
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DIDLLite));
DIDLLite device = (DIDLLite)ser.Deserialize(reader);
```

Class `DIDLLite`:

```
[XmlRoot("DIDL-Lite", Namespace = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/")]
public class DIDLLite {
    DIDLLite() {
        this.serviceItem = new List<ContainerItem>();
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(ServiceListTypeService), IsNullable = false)]
    List<ContainerItem> serviceItem = new List<ContainerItem>();
}
```

Class `ContainerItem`:

```
public class ContainerItem
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("parentID")]
    public string parentID { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("restricted")]
    public string restricted { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("searchable")]
    public string searchable { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add in the namespaces to the NamespaceManager as well, and then feed it into the XmlSerializer. I'm just recollecting this off the top of my head, will post a full answer once I remember it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. you define an `XmlArrayItem` attribute - but really, in your XML, you don't have any list of items. If you want to use an Xml array construct, you'd need to have something like this for your XML:

   ```
   <DIDL-Lite .....>
       <Items>
          <item id="28" parentID="19" restricted="1">
           ......
          </item>
          <item id="29" parentID="19" restricted="1">
           ......
          </item>
       </Items>
   </DIDL-Lite>
   ```

   So you would need to have an `<Items>...</Items>` wrapper around your `<item>` elements.
2. You have this declaration:

   ```
   [XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(ServiceListTypeService), IsNullable = false)]
   ```

   but where is the `ServiceListtypeService` defined? I don't see any trace of it....

I simplified your code a bit - and this works just fine:

```
[XmlRoot("DIDL-Lite", Namespace = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/")]
public class DIDLLite
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public ContainerItem Item { get; set; }
}


public class ContainerItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("parentID")]
    public string parentID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("restricted")]
    public string restricted { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("searchable")]
    public string searchable { get; set; }

    // you were missing these elements and their namespace

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")]
    public string creator { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")]
    public string date { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

And now, when I run your code to deserialize your XML, I do get the objects filled nicely.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy.